# Zooming an SVG map with translate and scale; how to improve performance?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I've created a pretty basic choropleth map in SVG, and I've implemented a zoom to bounding box function so that when you click on a zone in the map, it zooms until this zone fills the viewport. The zoom transition is very janky and slow however.

The SVG is generated in a React application with React-Spring for the transitions and animations. I thought I'd make sure that the problem wasn't somehow linked to React. However I've made a codesandbox to test this that contains only rendered SVG and a simple piece of javascript to run a transition between the start and the end of the zoom. I can see that the problem isn't React because the transition is still janky and slow.

https://codesandbox.io/s/4qom1wmno9

I'd expect a map like this that isn't that complicated to not be so slow in this transition. It's made up of fairly simple geometries; generated from a topojson file that weighs less than 30kb and there are only 280 or so `path` rendered.

Comment: That's 256kb or so of svg.Opening it in Inkscape then saving it as an optimized svg crunches this down to about 30kb. You don't need all those places after the decimal point, nor do you need the lengthy `rgb(r, g, b)` color notation (html hex notation is okay) I also note it's considerably faster on subsequent executions - the first is slower than the second, is slower than the third.

Comment: @enhzflep the SVG is generated with d3 geoPath, I can't downgrade the complexity of what the function returns for the d attribute.